# Swift for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode, kotlin

I'm learning how to create an app using Swift language for universities' purposes.

I would like to know:

**1st question:**

Could I create an app using Swift is it working for Android?
I saw the code of some Android apps and it seems similar syntax, these languages are new for me.

Xcode is very helpful, could I still use it for Android?

**2nd question:**

I read that if I develop apps using C# the code applies for both OS, so my question is:

Can I access to all features that Xcode provides using a language different from Swift like C#, C, C++, Java...?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: swift is different language, in android there is kotine , which somewhat quite similar to swift syntax wise, but swift and kotline are differenct

Comment: No and again no.

Answer (score 2):

## In general, no.

But you still can write your custom framework which will make communication between Swift and Android SDK. (And this is kind overhead for you purpose :D )

---

And also you can try cross-platform frameworks, for example:

- Xamarin(C#) for writing cross-platform applications for both platforms. More here [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin)
- Ionic, React Native, etc. (javascript) for writing cross-platform applications for both platforms but in this case using javascript. More here [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/), [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/).
- Flutter(Dart) also cross-platform framework by Google. More here
  [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/)

Or you can check native development only for one platform:

- iOS (Swift, Obj.C.) this two main languages for iOS/macOS app
  development.
- Android (Kotlin, Java, C++) these main languages for    Android app
  development.

---

Also, the community has a lot of frameworks like for example KotlinNative, which helps you writing business logic on Kotlin for two platforms.

**Summary**: *The smart way will be using the exact language for the chosen OS. Android(Java, Kotlin, C++) and iOS/macOS(Swift, Obj.C.) and same for IDE Android(Android studio), iOS/macOS(XCode, AppCode)*

P.S. Kotlin and Swift are really similar so on purpose it will take less time to switch to another platform.

Comment: Perfect, thank you all clear!